# Problem trying to read back zip list into original lists

Tags: python, list, csv, zip

3 Months new to learning Python, thanks to all for the help.  Amazing language.

Having an issue trying to read back a zip list saved to csv.

Here is how I'm writing the lists out to file..

```
def save_csv():
    buyall = list(zip(buycoin, buyprice, buyqty, buystatus))  
    with open('Trade Data.csv', 'wt') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(buyall)
```

How can I read these 4 lists back into the lists themselves when loading from file?
Having trouble figuring out the format..

Regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read comment in code

```
import csv

buycoin, buyprice, buyqty, buystatus = [
    (str(i), str(i)*(i+1), str(i)+'*') for i in range(4)]
print(buycoin, buyprice, buyqty, buystatus)
# ('0', '0', '0*') ('1', '11', '1*') ('2', '222', '2*') ('3', '3333', '3*')


def save_csv():
    buyall = list(zip(buycoin, buyprice, buyqty, buystatus))
    print(*buyall)
    # ('0', '1', '2', '3') ('0', '11', '222', '3333') ('0*', '1*', '2*', '3*')
    with open('Trade Data.csv', 'wt') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)  # remove quoting
        wr.writerows(buyall)  # row's'


def read_csv():
    with open('Trade Data.csv', 'rt') as myfile:
        data = csv.reader(myfile)
        data = [*zip(*data)]  # transpose
        return data


save_csv()
'''
0,1,2,3
0,11,222,3333
0*,1*,2*,3*
'''

a, b, c, d = read_csv()
print(a, b, c, d)
# ('0', '0', '0*') ('1', '11', '1*') ('2', '222', '2*') ('3', '3333', '3*')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael.  Unfortunately something is not quite right.. Getting this error.. c:\Temp\Project4>python rtest.py
('0', '0', '0*') ('1', '11', '1*') ('2', '222', '2*') ('3', '3333', '3*')
('0', '1', '2', '3') ('0', '11', '222', '3333') ('0*', '1*', '2*', '3*')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtest.py", line 27, in <module>
    a, b, c, d = read_csv()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)

Comment: Figured it out... I should not be using list(zip( to bundle, should be just zip.. list adds extra [ ] which causes it all to look like 1 (or 0?)  instead of 4.. :)  Thank you!